# "receive" is to "send" what "???" is to "scatter"

Tags: verbs, synonyms, transitive-verbs, general-vs-specific

I am looking for a word in English that is a synonym for *receive* but is specific for the process of another scattering something to many rather than  just sending individually.

- If one entity *sends* something, another entity *receives* that something.
- If one entity *scatters* something, other entities *individually* ... ??? ... (parts of) that something.

Possible near options are:

- *collect*/*gather*, but that sounds more to me that many are sending to one (many-to-one instead of one-to-many). As "the state collects taxes from individials".
- *catch*, seems more like a random process. As "one scatters coins, others catch these coins"

I am using the word *scatter* in the *distribute* sense, so if it helps we can work with:

- If one entity *distributes* something, other entities *individually* ... ??? ... (parts of) that something.

Comment: Is *scatter* the right word to start with?  In a lot of usages, a person or a machine is distributing a lot of small things like seeds or water droplets to a *common receiver* like a field or pavement. Can you give us another hint about what you’re trying to say?

Comment: In stead of scatter, you want something like *metes out* or *distributes*. *Scatters* specifically implies there aren't any intended receivers. Grass seed is scattered. Back stage passes are meted out. And the lucky ones still *receive* them.

Comment: @GlobalCharm, thank you. You are exactly right, this is the right context, a single computer _scatters_ data across a computer cluster. Therefore each computer in the cluster _receives_ that data. I am looking for a word more specific than _receive_. Incidentally, also _receive_ is a word already taken to describe the other end of an (invididual) _send_ , also I am stuck with the _scatter_ in the first place but you can think the question for other equivalent words (like _distribute_, I still have the question).

Comment: @PhilSweet, you are right. If you want, you can change _scatter_ by _distribute_ in my question if that helps. (+1 for _metes out_)

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't want to use "receive" for this. You may be misinterpreting the meaning of "receive". Are the receiving entities identified or at least distinct? Do they have to actually receive their allotted parts for the the verb to be appropriate,  or can it just be theoretical?

Comment: How about "gather," as in “Jerusalem, Jerusalem, who kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to her! How often I wanted to gather your children together, the way a hen gathers her chicks under her wings, and you were unwilling" (Jesus, in Matthew 23:37)

Comment: @Spencer, yes the entities are distinct and more over a verb that describes the action from their point of view is good to. Imagine you receiving something, while you know that others are also receiving.

Comment: @rhetorician, thanks. As you can see _gather_ is used as one receiving from many ("I .. gather", "a hen gathers"); and not many receiving from one.

Comment: Yeah, my first choice would be "gather", or some synonym such as "collect".

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on the accepted term (perhaps a metaphor) for receiving the thing being scattered. Would you say that each node on a network "sees" the scattered data? Sometimes, "receive" is the best word because everyone is intended to use what comes to them, e.g., manna.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is [accept](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/accept). According to the etymology on Wiktionary, it comes from the frequentative form of the Latin *accipio* (to take). The outlying nodes of your system can *accept* the messages that are *scattered* by the central node. *Taking* sounds slightly more active than *receiving* and may be closer to what you have in mind.

I am assuming from your use of the verb *scatter* that the messages are not distributed in an orderly way, but somehow broadcast until the receivers indicate that all of the messages have been received for processing. You could, for example, imagine a bag of candies being scattered on a table in front of a group of children. There are many verbs that you could use to describe the children handling the candies, all of which have connotations of orderly or disorderly behavior.

Generally speaking, for anything involving “decoupled forms” in computer architecture, I go to the original work on Design Patterns by the [Gang of Four](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), and look at the nouns they use for the classes and the verbs they use for the method calls. I don’t have my copy at hand right now, but I recall *accept* being used in some contexts like the one you describe.